# WebDriverError: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Hi tried to run selenium test in docker.

```
const { Builder, By} = require("selenium-webdriver");
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const assert = require('assert')

async function addCadastreTest() {
    const options = new chrome.Options()
    options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true)
    let driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser("chrome")
        .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .build();
    
    await driver.get("http://localhost:3000/");
    await driver.findElement(By.id("fit")).click()

    assert(await driver.switchTo().alert().getText() == "Quel est le nom de votre commune ?")
    {
      const alert = await driver.switchTo().alert()
      await alert.sendKeys("Lons le Saunier")
      await alert.accept()

    }
    await driver.quit();
}
addCadastreTest();
```

This is the stacktrace of the error :

```
mapbox\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:522
    let err = new ctor(data.message)
              ^

WebDriverError: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.61)
    at Object.throwDecodedError mapbox\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:522:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (mapbox\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:549:13)
    at Executor.execute (mapbox\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:475:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Object.execute (mapbox\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:735:17)
    at async addCadastreTest (mapbox\test\addCadastre.spec.js:14:5) {
  remoteStacktrace:
```

I'm stuck because i tried to run this test in java with selenium in docker and it work but in JavaScript i get this weird error connection refused. If someone have a thought to solve my problem thank.

Comment: Try using "127.0.0.1" for your .get()... right now you've got a grid running on localhost, your test website server, and also possibly Selenium itself.  Might also check logs to see if the port is an issue.  Running local instead of via grid might also help.